# Are prisoners who are doing time allowed to act as a lawyer, or to practise law in any capacity?

Tags: united-states, lawyer, prison

I was watching the TV series The Rookie and in season 3 episode 8, an inmate called Oscar Hutchinson is allowed out of prison under supervision to help with a case. The suspect is his daughter, although he doesn't know her. He then acts as her lawyer. He has passed the bar, and he is only family through blood. Is he then allowed to be her lawyer? Keep in mind, he is out of prison, so that is not a problem.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! However, it's a good idea to wait a day or so before accepting an answer; that way, if anyone else comes up with one better than mine, you can accept theirs instead. You can always accept a different answer if one is posted, but a lot of people generally don't write new answers to questions that already have an accepted answer, so it's probably a good idea to un-accept mine for now. If you still think it's the best one after a day or so, then feel free to accept it again.

Comment: thanks for the tip! as you have maybe seen, I am new here. So thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [oklahoma](/questions/tagged/oklahoma), **no, a lawyer is not allowed to practice law from prison**. This was decided by the Supreme Court of the State of Oklahoma in [State ex rel. Oklahoma Bar Association v. Silvernail](https://www.oscn.net/applications/oscn/DeliverDocument.asp?CiteID=492496).

> Respondent Jay Silvernail was licensed to practice law in Oklahoma in 2009. In 2016, he was charged in Oklahoma County District Court, Case No. CF-2016-4381, with Assault and Battery with a Deadly Weapon. In October 2019, a jury found him guilty and recommended a sentence of two and one-half years in prison. Silvernail was immediately taken into custody pending formal sentencing. In November 2019, the Oklahoma Bar Association (OBA) filed an application for immediate interim suspension, pursuant to Rule 6.2A, Rules Governing Disciplinary Proceedings (RGDP), 5 O.S.2011, ch. 1, app. 1-A. The OBA claimed that Silvernail was violating ethical rules by continuing to practice law while in the county jail.
>
> ...
>
> While in jail awaiting formal sentencing, Silvernail made a number of phone calls to his mother, daughter, and brother concerning his law practice.4 These family members are not attorneys, although Silvernail's daughter had apparently served as his office manager. The conversations generally involved monitoring Silvernail's open cases, managing the firm's accounts, and arranging for fellow attorneys to stand in for Silvernail and seek continuances on pending matters. In one call, Silvernail estimated that he had 60 to 70 active cases. In another, Silvernail told his mother to deposit any checks received from clients directly into his operating account, rather than his client trust account.
>
> As these conversations make clear, Silvernail thought he could continue to represent existing clients while he remained in jail. In fact, he believed he could take on new clients as well. Silvernail thought that so long as he could find attorneys to stand in for him at hearings, he could operate his practice vicariously, as a sort of general manager. At the same time, Silvernail expressed more concern with justifying the receipt and retention of client funds, rather than effectively representing the clients themselves. He even expressed strong reluctance at giving the stand-in attorneys access to client files: "If I give that file to [another lawyer], why is somebody going to pay me?" When discussing the possibility of taking on new clients, Silvernail reasoned that once the client agreed to pay his firm, "I can send any practicing attorney to any court case."
>
> ...
>
> Nevertheless, when Silvernail's conduct while awaiting sentencing is viewed as a whole, it is clear that he was not acting in his clients' best interests, and that he placed his own financial motives first. **The obstacles to effective representation from a jail cell should be obvious.** As an inmate, Silvernail was unable to confer with clients confidentially. He was unable to communicate freely with prosecutors or other opposing counsel about his clients' cases. He was obviously unable to appear in court on his clients' behalf. His ability to access legal resources, a computer, or even his own clients' files, was hampered to say the least. Finally, practicing law from a jail cell arguably gives the appearance of impropriety. **These conditions would have prompted a reasonable attorney to take a different tack.**

(emphasis added)

Note that part of the reason his actions were ruled to be unethical is that he "was unable to confer with clients *confidentially*." Because this was part of the reason, the situation described in the question of the lawyer-prisoner being "allowed out of prison *under supervision*" is problematic, even if he can "appear in court on his clients' behalf." The potential argument that practicing law from jail "arguably gives an appearance of impropriety" could also be applied to a lawyer being let out of jail only to practice law.

Jay Silvernail was disbarred as a result of his actions.